# Get attribute using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Given HTML structure like so:

```
<dd itemprop="actors">
    <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <a itemprop="name">Yumi Kazama</a>,                 </span>

<span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <a itemprop="name">Yuna Mizumoto</a>,               </span>

<span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <a itemprop="name">Rei Aoki</a>,                        </span>
</dd>
```

How to get all value of `a/text()`, for the all `itemprop="name"` element?

url:

```
//*[@itemprop='actors']//*[@itemprop='name']/text()
```

is getting only first `a/text`.

Comment: Just looking at the link OP posted, it seems to be highly inappropriate or even abusive for this forum. I am flagging this. Others, raise concerns if any.

Comment: Your xpath works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your html file is **test.html** the following should work:

```
from lxml import html

with open(r'E:/backup/GoogleDrive/py/scrapy/test.html', "r") as f:
    page = f.read()
tree = html.fromstring(page)
names = tree.xpath("//a[@itemprop='name']//text()")
print names
```